# How do I prevent vue.js from overwriting jQuery bindings in components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am implementing vue.js in an existing project and bound the vue instance on the body tag with an id of "app".

So far so good, jQuery and Vue.js playing along really well. However, the moment I create components all my jQuery bindings within those components are not working anymore.

The bindings in the root instance however are still functioning.

The HTML:

```
<body id="app">

<button class="button-app" @click="showMessage('app')">APP</button>

<some-component inline-template>
    <div>
        <button class="button-component" @click="showMessage('component')">COMPONENT</button>
    </div>
</some-component>

</body>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('.button-app').on('click', function()
{
    console.info('jQuery: app');
});

$('.button-component').on('click', function()
{
    console.info('jQuery: component');
});

var Component = Vue.extend({
    methods: {
        showMessage: function(message)
        {
            console.info('vue.js component: ' + message);
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        showMessage: function(message)
        {
            console.info('vue.js: ' + message);
        }
    },
    components: {
        'some-component': Component
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle to show and prove what I described above:
https://jsfiddle.net/z7o8wkz7/2/

Is that normal behaviour or can I do something to keep jQuery bindings in components alive?

**EDIT:**

Since I am using pjax, jquery and vuejs I have solved the correct loading order in the following way:

*app.js:*

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:end', function() {

    // init vue.js and load components here

    $(document).trigger('vue:loaded');
});
```

*some-query-file.js:*

```
$(document).on('vue:loaded', function() {

    // bind jquery stuff

});
```

This makes sure that the jQuery bindings are (re-)evaluated after the pjax has loaded and the vue components have been initialized. Works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a component, Vue.js compiles your template (inline or not) and insert it into the document ([lifecycle](http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle_Diagram)).

Hence, you should attach the jQuery events after the **root instance of Vue** or reinitiate them into the `ready` function, because the component will change the DOM.

#### Examples

[Into the ready function](https://jsfiddle.net/z7o8wkz7/3/)

[After the root instance](http://jsfiddle.net/z7o8wkz7/4/)

Comment: thanks! sounds logical :) unfortunately in my real scenario it's a bit more complicated since I am also using pjax. so i guess i have to make sure to keep the right order of invoking scripts or make use of the vuejs ready function...

Comment: found a solution for the loading order and edited my post above. thanks again, @pespantelis

Comment: Thx, fixed my (exact same) problem!

Answer (score -1):

put jquery code inside the mounted function